# Automating 3D Modeling using NLP

Tags: nlp, 3d-reconstruction, chatbot

I would like to know if there is any way we can automate 3D modeling processes. Like if I give the model a text input such as "create a sphere and give it a red color" and the we need to get the model. To be precise, I would like to create a bot that can perform actions in a software such as blender, like I tell the bot what I would like to do and then it does it. Any idea how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Well sure it's doable: the NLP part is just speech recognition + extracting the formal command from the text, it's very similar to "virtual assistants" like Apple Siri, Amazon Alexa, Ok Google.

However the hard part is to formalize all the possible commands that can be given, and then train a model to correctly map voice commands to software instructions.

I'm not convinced that it's very useful, because giving detailed instructions like "move object to position x=3.45678, y=-9.8765, z=1.2345" is not as intuitive as using a mouse to move the object. There's a fallacy in imagining that language commands are easier than learning to use a software or programming language: it works for very simple tasks, but as soon as one needs a bit of precision general language is too ambiguous.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, whatever you told makes sense, I am just trying to make an assistant for a software such as blender, you mentioned about extraction of formal command from the text, can you brief a little on that and coming to the general language being more ambiguos, I am thinking of limiting the commands to more basic commands, that should work right?

Comment: @Loukik sure, it's definitely a good idea to start with a subset of the most basic commands because this way you can test how well it works in this simple setting, and if it works well you can extend to more commands later.

Comment: yeah I will probably do that, but in the future I might have to do some research on how to make the the model understand more than basic commands, let me know if you find any in the future maybe, thanks for sharing your knowledge